# can't update data to database(codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have this code in my update function, when i try other value the table updates but when i used that value($field8) the table don't update.

```
   public function edit_lead() {
       $id = "3";
       $field8 ="http://38.102.225.87/RECORDINGS/MP3/20170201-094849_7188352209-all.mp3";
       $this->db->set('field8', $field8);
       $this->db->where('id', $id);
       $query = $this->db->update('table');
       if($query) {
            return true;
       } else {
            return false;
       }
   }
```

Comment: $ID ??? you forgot to set ID

Comment: sorry forgot to put it. but in my code there is, the problem is when used the value of field8, my update dont work. but when i used other value for it my update works.

Comment: check to your db field, If it set enough length for the data. for example: VARCHAR (250)

Comment: yes the length is already VARCHAR(255)

Comment: maybe problem is unescaping data - can you try $field8 = $this->db->escape($field8);

Comment: i determine my new problem, when i used it as a static value it works but when it come from post it doesn't work

Comment: How you get value? Is it like that; $field8 = $this->input->post('field8');

Comment: this how my code look like $field8 = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('field8'));

Answer (score 0):

Simply send the id of the user as a parameter of this function..

`public function edit_lead($ID) {
}`